# Консоль-PHP

Tags: cmd, php, консоль, exec

Итак, есть консоль. Как ее открыть-оно вроде понятно, следующим кодом:

```
exec('путь до консоли', $output);
```

Вопрос первый, скрипт не будет выполняться дальше пока консоль не закроется? Если да, то как просто ее открыть, да чтобы скрипт дальше работал?
Так вот, основной вопрос, что меня терзает

***Как написать какой-либо текст в консоль?*** Как "подружить" php и постороннюю консоль, чтобы я мог скриптом писать в нее какой-либо текст и отправлять?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам наверное нужно

[proc-open()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.proc-open.php)

ну и это называется не консоль а потоки ввода-вывода

вот еще почитайте

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.stream-notification-callback.php

Comment: скопировал пример из мануала, поменял пару вещей...видимо криво поменял. Вот есть у меня файл. New.exe. Введешь ему цифру-он тебе ее выведет (простое эхо) и закрываться не будет после этого, но вот пишет он в файл ошибок в не понять какой кодировке, в этом и проблема. помогите разобраться, вот код: http://arc.zz.mu/code.txt

Comment: в файл ошибок идет stderr, как же я вам помогу, если это ошибки от New.exe ... скорее всего проблемы с запуском, винда ругается на что нить типа "нет доступа к файлу" я в этой OS не силен.  вы можете кстати, ошибки выводить не в файл а на экран - читайте этот поток как и 0 .

Comment: пожалуйста, можно больше примеров?

Comment: http://ideone.com/fISldD

тут я использую cat (что на stdin, то и на stdout)

http://ideone.com/sHdy45

тут пример с ошибкой

если у вас программа не выходит после закрытия каналов, то читайте вторую ссылку.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, все работает, уиии! :) А можно ли сделать тоже самое, только с уже открытой консолью? То есть консоль была открыта не php, а мною например.

Comment: нет такой штуки "консоль" есть потоки ввода-вывода stdin/stdout/sderr в простейших случаях, в случае, если вы открыли прогу как-то сами, то надо писать какую-нить систему коммуникации (в *nix делается через сокеты и прочее, в винде наверное что-то похожее есть)... не думаю что вы этим станете  заниматься

Comment: Смогу ли я перенаправить поток ввода вывода на, например, cmd, написав fopen(путькcmd, "w"); fwrite("woami");?

Comment: нет, вы можете написать 

    $process = proc_open('cmd', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);

для этого эта функция и придумана. вы можете не закрывать поток сразу после чтения, а читать только одну строку, и потом посылать ответ и читать ещё раз.

Answer (score 0):

Скрипт тебе в консоле надо исполнять? можно было бы скрипт в батник запихнуть и попробовать запустить через консоль этот батник.А в батнике уж прописать сколько ему работать

Цитата с php про команду system

> If a program is started with this
> function, in order for it to continue
> running in the background, the output
> of the program must be redirected to a
> file or another output stream. Failing
> to do so will cause PHP to hang until
> the execution of the program ends.

Надо для продолжения будет всё равно переправить на другой источник.

Ещё нашёл

> On WinXP with Apache2 and PHP 4.3.3
> you cannot start a program in
> background with exec and start. you
> have to do the following. This
> function should work on Windows and
> Unix, too.
>
> <?php function execInBackground($path,
> $exe, $args = "") {
>     global $conf;
>
> ```
> if (file_exists($path . $exe)) {
>     chdir($path);
>     if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
>         pclose(popen("start \"bla\" \"" . $exe . "\" " .
> ```
>
> escapeshellarg($args), "r")); 
>         } else {
>             exec("./" . $exe . " " . escapeshellarg($args) . " > /dev/null
> &"); 
>         }
>     } } ?>

Comment: второй кусок кода...это что?

Comment: Это пример запуска программы в фоновом режиме

Comment: простите, а зачем?